# If you pass an exception into Java's `System.out.println`, what happens?

Tags: java, printing

In java, we normally pass strings as input to `System.out.println`
What happens if you try to input something weird, such as an instance of the `Exception` class?

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args]) {
        System.out.println("printing a string is perfectly normal");
        Exception e = new Exception();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

What datatypes are allowed as input to `System.out.println`?
What happens if you attempt to print an instance of a class which `System.out.println` is not overloaded for?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: There's nothing special about exceptions in this case. An exception, like any other `Object` that's not already a string, is transformed to a string using the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It calls the overloaded method with the Object parameter, which looks like this:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
          print(s);
          newLine();
    }
}
```

This essentially prints `"null"` if the object is `null` and will print the result of calling `.toString` on the object otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> What datatypes are allowed as input to System.out.println?

Anything.

> What happens if you attempt to print an instance of a class which
> System.out.println is not overloaded for?

There is an overload for Object, and its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) says what happens: for the argument `x`, a call to `String.valueOf(x)` is made, and the result is printed.

And if you read the [documentation for that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)), it says that `x.toString()`will be called for non-null`x`.

In short, all objects have an accessible `toString()` method, and that is what determines what is printed.